# Special characteres error on saving XML file in Java ("<" and ">")

Tags: java, xml

I am trying to edit a specific key inside an XML file. The problem is that after the file is saved, the '<' and '>' characters are transformed in coded characters (respectively: "& lt;" and "& gt;").

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>

  </configSections>

  <system.web>    
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="X.X"/>
  </system.web>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add connectionString="Data Source=XXXX;user Id=YYYYY;password=ZZZZZ;" name="Entities" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"/>
  </connectionStrings>

</configuration>
```

I'm updating the value of the entire connectionStrings key:

```
package br.com.sedna.bitbucket.plugin.enviromentsetup.utils;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class ModifyXmlFile {
    private File _inputFile; 
    private String _filePath;
    private DocumentBuilderFactory _docFactory;
    private DocumentBuilder _docBuilder;
    private Document _doc;
    private Node _xmlObject;
    private String CONNECTION_STRINGS = "<add connectionString=\"Data Source=XXXX;user     Id=%s;password=ZZZZZ;\" name=\"Entities\"     providerName=\"Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client\"/>";

    public ModifyXmlFile(String xmlPath){

        try {
            this._filePath = xmlPath;
            this._inputFile = new File(this._filePath);             
            this._docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            this._docBuilder = _docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            this._doc = _docBuilder.parse(_inputFile);
            this._xmlObject = _doc.getFirstChild();

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public ModifyXmlFile setNodeValue(String nodeName, String nodeValue){

        Node nodeNameObject = this._doc.getElementsByTagName(nodeName).item(0);


        try {

            // updating the value of connectionStrings key
            nodeNameObject.setTextContent(String.format(CONNECTION_STRINGS, nodeValue));                

            TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer;

            transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "utf-8");

            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(this._doc);
            StreamResult consoleResult = new StreamResult(new File(this._filePath));
            transformer.transform(source, consoleResult);

            System.out.println("Done");
        } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TransformerException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return this;
    }
}
```

Running this class:

```
ModifyXmlFile xmlHelper = new ModifyXmlFile("C:\\Web.config");
xmlHelper.setNodeValue("connectionStrings", "NEWVALUE");
```

The result:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <configuration>
    <configSections>

    </configSections>

    <system.web>    
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="X.X"/>
    </system.web>

    <connectionStrings>&lt;add connectionString="Data Source=XXXX;user Id=NEWVALUE;password=ZZZZZ;" name="Entities" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"/&gt;</connectionStrings>
    </connectionStrings>

  </configuration>
```

I have tried changing the encode type without success.

Comment: You're using `setTextContent`: `nodeNameObject.setTextContent(String.format(CONNECTION_STRINGS, nodeValue));` So you're explicitly *asking* the document builder to ensure that it's treated as text, not markup. I don't know the lib well enough to point you at what you *should* use, but it's definitely not `setTextContent`.

Comment: in my experience, you should be using appendChild() and actually using the java XML library instead of trying to manually edit tags.  Also setNodeValue is a useful method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified the `setNodeValue` method. The relevant part follows:

```
    public ModifyXmlFile setElementAttributeValue(String nodeXPath, String attributeName, String newAttributeValue) throws XPathExpressionException{

    try {
        XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        Node node = (Node)xPath.evaluate(nodeXPath,  _doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
        node.getAttributes().getNamedItem(attributeName).setNodeValue(String.format(CONNECTION_STRINGS, newAttributeValue));
```

Calling this via

```
setElementAttributeValue("/configuration/connectionStrings/add",     "connectionString", "NEWVALUE" );
```

changes the value of the attribute `connectionString` on the element `add`.

There are several problems in the original code:

- the `consoleResult` is named confusingly - the `StreamResult` points to a file
- the parameter `nodeName` actually stands for parent node of the element to be edited and this is indeed what is retrieved per `this._doc.getElementsByTagName(nodeName).item(0)` - at least when `setNodeValue` is called with `"connectionStrings"` for `nodeName`.
- the name of the attribute to be edited is hard-wired into the code.
- as  T.J. Crowder mentioned, the `setTextContent` method the original code is calling is used to set text content, i.e. the text between >< of some element. It is neccessary to distinguish between elements, attributes and text content and be aware of the fact that these are not interchangeable. It is not possible to add new element by adding text content which looks like (is formatted like) an element.

Please note that the new code is not production ready as at the very least the handling of potential `null` values would need to be added, e.g. on the result of  `getNamedItem(attributeName)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me. It worked like a charm. I'm fixing the code to avoid nullpointer exception and just renamed the variables to make the code clearer.